# Can i use only 1 dual rank ram for my notebook?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I have a dell notebook with 2 Ram slots, both have 4gb ram each (8gb total).

I want to upgrade my system to 16gb ram total. And i'd like to use just 1 ram slot for now and keep the other one empty so i started to look for 1x16gb rams. i found out Kingston KVR24S17D8/16 then i realize it's dual rank ram. After some research online, i found out that dual rank rams must be used 2 pieces with 2 slots. (such as 2 rams of 8gb)

My question is, if i use only 1 dual rank ram (16gb - KVR24S17D8/16), will i have any troubles with my notebook and my gaming performance?

Comment: What model is your notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The Dell inspiron 15 gaming 7577 can accept one RAM stick of 16GB.
However, I'm not sure that your memory is acceptable.

The Kingston RAM model KVR24S17D8/16 is not in the list of upgrades of
[Kingston Dell Inspiron 15 (7577) Gaming Laptop RAM Memory](https://www.kingstonmemoryshop.co.uk/ram-memory-upgrades/laptop/dell/inspiron-15-7000-series/dell-inspiron-15-7577-gaming-laptop).
Therefore I would judge it unsuitable, even knowing that motherboards can sometimes
adapt themselves to unsuitable RAM (although perhaps with performance lose).
I recommend choosing RAM from that list.

You should also have a look at
[Crucial RAM for Dell Inspiron 15 7577](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/dell/inspiron-15-(7577)),
as they have competitive prices.